# I'm looking for the simplest way to produce a 1-bit high resolution (1080p or so) DVI signal

Tags: arduino

It doesn't need to be high performance, I just need to draw a bit mask.

I'll be driving it from a micro controller, arduino or perhaps a BeagleBone Black.

The application is to produce structured light patterns with a off-the-shelf projector.

Comment: Do you mean DVI-D or DVI-A signals (the latter are just plain VGA)?

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi 4 has two HDMI ports. Use one for your UI and the other for your structured light generation.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/

Answer (score 0):

I'd go to the Raspberry Pi for the HDMI output instead of the Beaglebone black, and just use an HDMI to DVI converter, like [http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-Adapter-Plated-Connector-Female/dp/B000FUVNX8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FUVNX8)

Comment: I'm hoping to preserve the 'normal' computer interface stuff for an actual UI for the device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, 1080p requires a 139MHz clock rate [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Specifications). Good luck getting that with an arduino or any bog-standard mcu, not to mention signal integrity issues if you don't design this properly.

A Beaglebone may be up to the task, I have no experience with them, but then you are probably looking more at software piping stuff out through HDMI. This is much the same as using a Raspberry Pi or other PC-related stuff, where the programming probably will be easier than writing mcu-specific firmware to do this.

If you want a challenge, you could try using an FPGA on a devboard, for example the ZedBoard [[2]](http://zedboard.org). This is a more expensive way (both in time and money) of doing it, though.

Good luck, whatever you end up doing! :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been leaning towards the BBB. Its PRUs run at 200mhz and offer strict 5ns timing for each operation.

Comment: I also found this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tfp410.pdf Which looks like it will deal with a lot of the DVI details.

Comment: I'm not sure you can bitbang the BBBs outputs at 139/165MHz though, especially if you need to do some processing... Why not just use the HDMI out from it and use a passive HDMI->DVI-converter for like $5?

Comment: Because I want to use the normal display for UI. The PRUs can probably do it... The processing will all be done in user-space on the main CPU and written to shared memory. The PRU would just need to copy bits from memory out to the DVI.

Comment: It's worse than that, actually. 1080p60 has a **pixel** clock of 139 MHz, which means a TMDS clock of 1390 MHz. You aren't bit-banging this from anything.